# Get list of index values of pixels of indexed image

Tags: imagemagick, netpbm

I would like to get the index values of an indexed image, so that I can modify images in a game where the palette and the index data are separate files. I looked through the command-line options of `identify`, the `-grayscale` options, the FX expressions and tried the `txt:-` output format, but they all don't seem to do the trick.

So if I have an image with a red, a blue, and another red pixel, saved as a GIF with a palette of 0: red and 1: blue, then I'd like to get an output similar to "0 1 0" or "\x00\x01\x00".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a 3-pixel French flag similarly to @xenoid like this:

```
magick xc:red xc:white xc:blue +append french.gif
```

You can dump the colormap and pixels using `MAP` format like this:

```
magick french.gif map: | xxd
00000000: ff00 0000 00ff ffff ff00 0000 0002 01    ...............
```

Hopefully you can see the first three bytes are red `0xff 00 00`, the next three are blue `0x00 00 ff` and the next three are white `0xff ff ff` and the last three are indices 0, 2, 1.

---

If you go Irish, with lime, white and orange:

```
magick xc:lime xc:white xc:orange +append irish.gif 
magick irish.gif map: | xxd
00000000: 00ff 00ff a500 ffff ff00 0000 0002 01    ...............
```

It may come in handy to know how many colours there are:

```
identify -format %k irish.gif
3
```

It may come in handy to use JSON to extract the number of entries in the colormap and their values:

```
magick irish.gif json: | jq -r '.[].image | .colormapEntries'                  
4

magick irish.gif json: | jq -r '.[].image | .colormap'       
[
  "#00FF00FF",
  "#FFA500FF",
  "#FFFFFFFF",
  "#000000FF"
]
```

---

Or you can use **PIL/Pillow** from Python:

```
python3 -c 'from PIL import Image; print(list(Image.open("irish.gif").getdata()))'
```

**Sample Output**

```
[0, 2, 1]
```

**PIL/Pillow** can also output the palette - though you need to be aware that it pads the palette out to 256 entries using shades of grey:

```
python3 -c 'from PIL import Image; print(list(Image.open("irish.gif").getpalette()))'
[0, 255, 0, 255, 165, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 92, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 121, 122, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 125, 125, 125, 126, 126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 132, 132, 132, 133, 133, 133, 134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 139, 139, 139, 140, 140, 140, 141, 141, 141, 142, 142, 142, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147, 147, 148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 151, 151, 151, 152, 152, 152, 153, 153, 153, 154, 154, 154, 155, 155, 155, 156, 156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 158, 158, 158, 159, 159, 159, 160, 160, 160, 161, 161, 161, 162, 162, 162, 163, 163, 163, 164, 164, 164, 165, 165, 165, 166, 166, 166, 167, 167, 167, 168, 168, 168, 169, 169, 169, 170, 170, 170, 171, 171, 171, 172, 172, 172, 173, 173, 173, 174, 174, 174, 175, 175, 175, 176, 176, 176, 177, 177, 177, 178, 178, 178, 179, 179, 179, 180, 180, 180, 181, 181, 181, 182, 182, 182, 183, 183, 183, 184, 184, 184, 185, 185, 185, 186, 186, 186, 187, 187, 187, 188, 188, 188, 189, 189, 189, 190, 190, 190, 191, 191, 191, 192, 192, 192, 193, 193, 193, 194, 194, 194, 195, 195, 195, 196, 196, 196, 197, 197, 197, 198, 198, 198, 199, 199, 199, 200, 200, 200, 201, 201, 201, 202, 202, 202, 203, 203, 203, 204, 204, 204, 205, 205, 205, 206, 206, 206, 207, 207, 207, 208, 208, 208, 209, 209, 209, 210, 210, 210, 211, 211, 211, 212, 212, 212, 213, 213, 213, 214, 214, 214, 215, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 217, 217, 217, 218, 218, 218, 219, 219, 219, 220, 220, 220, 221, 221, 221, 222, 222, 222, 223, 223, 223, 224, 224, 224, 225, 225, 225, 226, 226, 226, 227, 227, 227, 228, 228, 228, 229, 229, 229, 230, 230, 230, 231, 231, 231, 232, 232, 232, 233, 233, 233, 234, 234, 234, 235, 235, 235, 236, 236, 236, 237, 237, 237, 238, 238, 238, 239, 239, 239, 240, 240, 240, 241, 241, 241, 242, 242, 242, 243, 243, 243, 244, 244, 244, 245, 245, 245, 246, 246, 246, 247, 247, 247, 248, 248, 248, 249, 249, 249, 250, 250, 250, 251, 251, 251, 252, 252, 252, 253, 253, 253, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 255]
```

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning how to get the palette. Before I manually parsed it from `identify -verbose`, but this makes it much easier. Looks like the three zero bytes before the indices 0, 2, 1 is padding, at least these bytes disappear when I add a fourth green pixel at the end.

Comment: @MarkSetchell.  What is MAP?  Is that Imagemagick? I do not see it at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/. Where is the documentation for it?

Comment: @fmw42 It's under `identify -list format`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IM's `convert` to convert an image to XPM  and get the pixel color indices:

For instance this 9x3 French flag:

[image]

Produces this:

```
/* XPM */
static char *FrenchFlag[] = {
/* columns rows colors chars-per-pixel */
"9 3 3 1 ",
"  c #0026FF",
". c #FF2900",
"X c white",
/* pixels */
"   XXX...",
"   XXX...",
"   XXX..."
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this trick. I wasn't aware of this image format. I think I'll give it another 2 days before accepting this solution, as I think there must be a better way with less complex text post-processing involved.